# Checkbox in li element doesn't trigger css :checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, checked

Is this impossible? I've created a responsive menu system, but the :checked event of my checkbox doesn't get caught in my css

**CSS**

```
#sectiona:checked + #asection {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li >
    <label for="sectiona" class="showhide">Search for a term</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sectiona" value="button" style="display:none;"/>                   
</li>
```

I've see something like this before. If this isn't possible, I'll have to redesign my menus. It has to be HTML and CSS. No Javascript is allowed...

Comment: Where is this `#asection`?

Comment: Your given code example you should try this selector `li + #sectiona:checked`

Comment: use js, if understood correctly not possible with just css

Comment: I've now removed the <ul> and i'm working on getting the :checked recognized by the CSS. As I've said in other comments, I've inspected the checkbox, and it seems to be changing...

Comment: What I suspect you are trying to do is affect an element **outside** the `li` by clicking on the `label/input`...this is **not possible** with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If undersood correctly you trying to show/hide checkbox input based on label click.

the `visibility` could do the trick.

Css:

```css
input#sectiona:checked  {
   visibility: visible;
}

input#sectiona {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<li >
<label for="sectiona" class="showhide">Search for a term</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="sectiona" value="button" />                   
</li>
```

in that case you can also add `display: block;`

```
input#sectiona:checked  {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```